# two word commands commands C++

Tags: c++, command, cpu-word

hello sorry to bother you,  I'm trying to write two-word commands
the user will type let's say "go north" I want my program to grab this both words and put them separately in variables, the program I wrote is doing but when I type one word command he compiler is waiting for second command how can I write this simple way to say if there is not second command grab input 1 without waiting second entry thank you

```
    cin >> input1 >> input2;
    if(!(input2==""))
    {
        if (input1 == "take" or input1 == "grab" or input1 == "go")
            input = input2;
        else
            input = input1;
    }
    else
        input = input1;
    input = format(input);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options: You can use [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read a full line and then parse that line. The way to fix your code with minimum changes would be to first read one word then the other, not both at once:

```
cin >> input1;
if (input1 == "take" or input1 == "grab" or input1 == "go") {
    cin >> input2;
    input = input2;
} else {
    input = input1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wont to get input longer then one word you neet to use [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

```
std::string command;
std::getline(cin, command);
```

and to pars the line you can use [boost::split](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html)

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
boost::split(words, command, boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

so your code should loke something like this

```
std::string command;
std::getline(cin, command);
std::vector<std::string> words;
boost::split(words, command, boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

and now do your command check